# Billing information is not displaying in magento one page checkout while checkout process

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.5

I have a magento website,

While checkout (when we click on checkout button) the billing information is not displaying and i am getting blank page with no fields and form except the header and footer,

But when i analyze the same thing in firebug, i can see that part is there, but not displaying on actual page.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: site url- www.citydamsel.com

Comment: I have already tried clearing cache, increasing memory_limit but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding **jQuery** BEFORE prototype... which is not the best idea. Remember that magento uses prototype.
Change the order of JS files and make sure that **jQuery.noConflict();** is added right after you add **jQuery.**

You are also adding jQuery 2 times:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/js/lightboxes/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/skin/frontend/default/helloresponsive/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also use only:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

assigning it to variable... I've never seen that working

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

just leave
 jQuery.noConflict(); right after you add only 1 instance of jQUERY.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where do i make changes? which file you are talking about?

Comment: I've checked your page source and saw jQuery added 2 times. You need to make changes to XML files and some template files

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in your local.xml OR page.xml and include your jquery in that layout file.

Still if you want change the load order you can try the below code

```
<default>
<update handle=”add_jquery_first” />
</default>

<add_jquery_first>
<action method="addJs" block="head">
<file>jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js</file>
</action>
</add_jquery_first>
```

Comment: @supal jquery is included but twice as MagentoNinja said..But your priority is to include prototype first and then jquery. The current source is like below.
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/js/lightboxes/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>

while it should be like this
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.citydamsel.com/js/lightboxes/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>